# Pagination API until error returns in nodejs

Tags: node.js, pagination, try-catch, offset

I am trying to read out an API with now more then 24k bots and increasing.

From API I can't get info on max bots count, so I need to paginate by offset and read all out until an error is raised or response is null / nothing.(While loop , try catch?)

I searched all internet and cant find a useful example.
My base code to read out the first 100 works.
Which approach would be the best to read out all bots even if is unknow the quantity?

```
const botsInfo = async () => {
        let botsdata = await api.getBots({
            account_id:'',
            limit: 100,
            offset: 1,
            scope: 'enabled',
        })
        botsdata.forEach(function(b) {
        console.log(b);
        })
    }
```

Sorry to ask this but I am now stuck on this for few days. I have some basic knowledge in nodejs.

Comment: do you have experience with sequelize? if yes, then I'll share here the implementation.. I just haven't idea what "getBots" method means, and what's the "api" object there

Comment: No mate i dont have experience with sequelize. i was more thinking to use an while loop and increase offsets. but i can answer on the getBots: https://github.com/3commas-io/3commas-official-api-docs/blob/master/bots_api.md